# Want a PrincipalPermission SecurityException on REST service to return 403, not 400 Bad Request

Tags: c#, rest, principalpermission

I have a RESTful (WCF) service decorated with PrincipalPermission demands.  I expected a `403 FORBIDDEN` response if the user does not hold the role, but get a `400 BAD REQUEST`, instead.  Upon reflection, this makes sense - the demand triggers a `SecurityException` when the principal doesn't hold the role; it's not the same as granting access through an `<authorization>` tag in the web.config.

However, a `400 BAD REQUEST` doesn't make sense... the request wasn't malformed, I just didn't have permission to make the call.  A `400` response implies I could fix the request and try again, but that will never succeed.

How could I intercept or map a `SecurityException` to a more appropriate response (preferably `403 FORBIDDEN`)?

Decorated method:

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "FST")]
public string TestNoPermissions(string NetworkId) {
    return "Call succeeded";
}
```

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Request Error</title>
    <style>BODY { color: #000000; ...;}</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <p class="heading1">Request Error</p>
      <p>The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'Access is denied.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is: </p>
      <p>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]&amp; outputs)
            at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
            at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
            at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
            at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement an [`IErrorHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler(v=vs.110).aspx) to intercept the `SecurityException`. and then provide a [`WebFaultException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd989924.aspx) with the status code.

```
public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
{
    if (error is SecurityException)
    {
        var faultEx = new WebFaultException<string>("Forbidden", HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)

        fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, faultEx.CreateMessageFault(), null);
    }
}
```

Note this is untested - security exceptions have a nasty habit of getting lost within frameworks / pipelines but this idea was a bit long for a comment.

Usually you would add your custom IErrorHandler with a behavior, which can be configured in your DI code or in config.

```
public class ErrorHandlerBehavior : IServiceBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
        // not implemented
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        foreach (var dispatcherBase in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
        {
            var dispatcher = dispatcherBase as ChannelDispatcher;

            if (dispatcher != null)
                dispatcher.ErrorHandlers.Add(new MyCustomErrorHandler());
        }
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        // not implemented
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will look more into this... leaving the question open a bit longer for more answers, but I suspect this is exactly what I'm after.

Comment: @JamesKing Did you get anywhere with this? I didn't test it and I'm not positive if it will work so I'm curious as to how you got on.

Comment: I'm working on researching the best way to implement an IErrorHandler, haven't forgotten... I'll report back as soon as I've gotten something stubbed out to test.  Part of the problem I have is that the service I'm working with is an older WCF service... I'm doing my testing on a new Web API 2 service with controllers and serializable models; if an IErrorHandler can be implemented against the WCF service, great, else I'm not opposed to migrating the WCF service.

Comment: @JamesKing - I've edited to show how to add it to a behavior

Comment: Thanks - in the end, for a number of other reasons, I've moved the code into a rest service.  I implemented an IErrorHandler there per your suggestion, and everything worked excellently!

Comment: Glad to hear it